# Git: Problems adding complete Android Studio folder

Tags: git, github

I have copied my Android Studio project's folder to my local GitHub directory and I'm trying to push it using `git add .`. However, it shows `(modified content, untracked content)` behind the directory's name, and the directory is not added.

I've tried removing the `.gitignore` files and adding the directory from the git bash in the folder itself, but that does not work. What could I do?

Comment: `git add -a` for staging all changes, `git add .` is for adding untracked files

Comment: @Thomas Eh? `git add .` is not for staging/adding merely untracked files. It stages/adds all changes in the current directory (and subdirs). The `-a` switch goes above and beyond to handle files that are normally considered "hidden", it apparently also handles removed stuff, according to the docs.

Comment: Using `git add -A` also doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you tell us what OS and shell you're using (re: what program is showing the "behind the directory's name")? That now seems to be highly relevant to your issue. Also, please list out the commands you've used, in order.

Answer (score 1):

Normal workflow for a new project to commit everything except for what is excluded with the `.gitignore`:

- `git init` create local repo
- `git add .` add every file not excluded with `gitignore`
- `git commit -m "init"` create a commit with a message `-m`
- `git remote add origin <remote repository URL>` add the remote, for example github
- `git push origin master` push to the newly added remote

From then on:

- make changes
- `git stash` stashes your changes for you on a sort of Clipboard (copy)
- `git checkout -b <new branch name>`
- `git stash apply` paste the changes to this new branch
- `git add -p` and select the changes you want to commit in the next step
- `git commit -m "bla` add a message to commit
- `git push origin <branch name from before>`

Answer (score 0):

Your command line shell is likely just showing that you did not yet do `git commit` (usually performed after `git add`).

There's also the possibility that you have files that were deleted, in which case `git add -u .` would be helpful, too (in addition to the regular `git add`). And... `git add -a` might be a nice option, too. You'd still want to commit after adding/staging the modifications.

Comment: Nope, I did commit it, and it still doesn't work. The folder is shown on GitHub.com, but it has a grey icon and is unclickable.